# How can I use Laravel localization inside blade components

Tags: php, laravel, translation, laravel-blade, laravel-localization

Inside my blade I have different components were someone are used in multiple blades so they need a different text. In my case my component has an attribute "title" were is different in the different blades that I use it.
Component:

```
<mycomponent title="Example" />
```

I try to use the "@lang()" helper but it dosent works it returns me an error, I also try:

```
<mycomponent title={{__('general.title')}} />
```

But it also returns me an error in my blade. Any idea of how can I do this?
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: "_But it also returns me an error_" What error?

Comment: try {!! trans('general.title') !!}

Comment: I solve the problem, the error that returns was that it dosen't find the end of the file. Btw thanks for your help I will post the solution.

Comment: @AqibJaved Try **avoid** using `{!!!!}` tag please. It is really dangerous for XSS attacks

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem searching in the Laravel documentation. According to what it says in the section: ***[Passing Data To Components](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#passing-data-to-components)*** what I have to do is:

```
<mycomponent :title="__('general.title')" />
```

The thing is that I didn't point out that I was using a blade component, sorry about that.

Hope this will be helpful for someone.